Android gradle not syncing
I downloaded a starter code online and the gradle sync keeps failing due to this errror :"Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/gradle/internal/impldep/com/google/common/collect/Lists".
I tried syncing multiple times

go to directory where the gradlew file is located.
Then in terminal run

./gradlew clean
./gradlew --stop
then run your application


It didn't work, thanks tho
